# WiFi Hotspot without any Password?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, passwords

I am interested to know is there any way to create a WiFi hotspot in Windows 10 without using any password...

I know the command with password...

> netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=Myhotspot key=password 
>   netsh start hosted network

It only starts hotspot with a password protection. I searched the whole Internet but I can't find any proper answer...

Once I have seen "connectify Hotspot" created an OPEN WiFi network with my PC... So I think it can also be done in command line. I don't want to use third-party software so please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: I'd suggest using a password regardless of how simple, as unless you live in the mountains away from anyone malicious, leaving it open is a huge risk. Just a suggestion, though.

Comment: **don't do that** unless you are happy to allow everybody to steal your bandwidth and use your internet connection for possibly illegal activities.

Comment: Following up on Hellreaver's comment: *any* password will serve as the seed for the encryption keys for the connections to your users. If you say you don't need a password, provide a simple one, maybe even put it in the SSID.

Comment: i live in a placee where , there is no moden technology comes user 5 km. no one have a wifi mobile in my area so i want..

Comment: have you tried just leaving the (key=) just like that and seeing if it connects? I dont have a wireless laptop over on my bench or i would test it out.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin leaving the `key` empty doesn't help

Comment: can you please tell me how to create an "Open Network ( without password )" using netsh command..?

Comment: Would this be possible: `key=""`? - my laptop accepted it, but I do not have Soft AP to actually start it.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this question is over 2 years old, but I feel that an answer would still be necessary here.

The reason why you can't find a proper answer to this is because unfortunately, you really aren't able to create a hotspot through the netsh command without a password (as far as I've seen). I don't think that the command was made with this option.

I'm pretty sure that Connectify doesn't use netsh. My guess is that it uses one of the drivers that are installed with Connectify to set up a hotspot. Again, this is just a guess - I don't know too much about Connectify and its internal functioning.